# Dual boot with Windows 10 in two different disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, laptop, grubrescue

I have a laptop (Xiaomi Air 12) with two SSDs, one with Windows 10 (let's call it sda), the other with Ubuntu (sdb). It may seem odd, but I can only boot from the first one (the BIOS doesn't let me change which disk to boot first).

I had some problems installing Ubuntu and GRUB the first time, after Windows was already installed. In particular I managed to do it (long ago) by making the GRUB start from the sda drive, adding an ext4 boot partition next to Windows 10 partitions - if I remember well...

Now I had to do a clean reinstall of Windows 10, and there the problem comes back: after windows 10 reinstall, no grub appears (obviously the system is booting the sda drive first, therefore it doesn't have the chance to look at the Ubuntu disk).
I tried to fix this using boot-repair tool from an Ubuntu live USB, getting "grub-rescue" screen if running it with recommended options. I also tried some other advanced options, but not solving anything - I don't understand most of the options, I don't want to cause any irreversible loss of data.
Anyway, I'm not quite understanding how should I set things up: where should I install the GRUB folder? On the web I found often "boot partition is not really necessary", does the boot partition actually matters in this case?

Apart from solving this issue right now, I would like to understand better how GRUB works along with disks and partitions.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Win 10 will often bypass grub once you boot into it, but this can be fixed. Need to see partitions. Run `sudo parted -l` from Live Ubuntu. Also are you running laptop in UEFI mode?

Comment: Here the output of `sudo parted -l` : https://pastebin.com/HTV6Gtg8

Actually here I was trying to create the boot partition in sda4: then I used boot-repair tool to install the grub into that partition, and it worked.

To answer your question, no, I'm in Legacy mode. If I switch to UEFI it immediately says 'No bootable device' right after pressing the power button.

What I acknowledged is that in my case I need an ext4 boot partition where to put the GRUB aside to windows partitions. Then the grub will load before Windows and will display the complete overview of the OSs. Am I right?

Comment: the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration only boots from MBR which then loads more code from other location. With two drives, best to keep Windows boot loader in Windows drive's MBR and grub in Ubuntu drive's MBR as grub only boots working Windows and sometimes you are going to need to directly boot it from UEFI/BIOS. New systems really should be UEFI. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt drives since 2012 and release of Windows 8. User only, can install in either old BIOS or newer UEFI boot mode. But you must have both systems in same boot mode.

Comment: Agree with oldfred. You really should be using UEFI system with a modern laptop. Back-up all data, then convert your sda (C:) drive to [GPT format](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10). Make sure you can boot to W10. Boot to Live Ubuntu. Open Gparted and convert the sdb drive to GPT, then re-install Ubuntu on it using primary partitions. Don't make any boot partitions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely do it. I did't know I was using a deprecated mode/disk formatting.

Comment: Hmm. Yes I agree. UEFI is best. You can convert Windows to UEFI using window's inbuilt MBR to GPT tool. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10